# Join 2 tables and replace the bad data with matching column data

Tags: sql

I have a requirement where I need to match a string in one of table and get the matching record of that table displayed. Please see below.

Table A

```
Column Address      
12333
W.Main  
street      
Apt     
402
```

Table B

```
Column Bad value , good value
Street              St
```

When I join both the table with left outer join I want Street from Table A to be replaced by the Mainvalue from Table B after lookin up in Table B.

As of now left join is displaying all nulls and adding a extra set of column, the main output should be like below. 
and then concentenate the below column data in 1 single row.
Like 12333 W.Main St Apt 402

12333
   W.Main
   St
   Apt
   402

So far I was able to do this.

```
   declare @id int
   declare @value varchar(1000)

   --select dbo.fnNumbersFromStr ('Richmond Plaza - Hwy. 74 E.')
   IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#TEMP') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #TEMP
    END 

   create table #Temp 
   (ID  int,
    Value varchar(max))

   insert into #Temp 
   SELECT * from MASTER.dbo.SplitWords('12333 W.Main street Apt 402')

   select * from #Temp

   select * from dbo.tStreetNameAbbrevations


   SELECT A.VALUE,B.strLookUpValue FROM #Temp AS A
   LEFT JOIN tStreetNameAbbrevations AS B
   ON A.Value = B.strBadValue
   where B.strLookupvalue is not null

    UPDATE #Temp
    set value = (SELECT B.strLookUpValue FROM #Temp AS A
    LEFT JOIN tStreetNameAbbrevations AS B
    ON A.Value = B.strBadValue
    where B.strLookupvalue is not null)
    where value in (SELECT A.VALUE FROM #Temp AS A
    LEFT JOIN tStreetNameAbbrevations AS B
    ON A.Value = B.strBadValue
    where B.strLookupvalue is not null)
```

Comment: You need to include the code for your query.

Answer (score 0):

Change your UPDATE statement to:

```
UPDATE #Temp
    SET Value = (SELECT strLookupValue 
                 FROM tStreetNameAbbrevations 
                 WHERE tStreetNameAbbrevations.strBadValue = #Temp.Value)
WHERE #Temp.ID IN (SELECT ID 
                   FROM #Temp 
                       INNER JOIN tStreetNameAbbrevations ON
                           tStreetNameAbbrevations.strBadValue = #Temp.Value)
```